# Misbehavior of a js-GRID inside a dialog while resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, resize, jsgrid

I have a js-GRID inside a dialog and when I resize it the appearance of js-GRID changes.

This is how my js-GRID looks like when loaded for the first time:

[loaded js-GRID for the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrcR2.png)

And this is how my js-GRID looks like **after trying to INCREASE** the dialog:

[js-GRID after resizing the dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqvj9.png)

This is the initialization code of my js-GRID inside this dialog.

```
$("#DataGrid").dialog({
    minWidth: 1240,
    minHeight: 600
});
$("#DataGrid").jsGrid({
    height: "100%",
    width: "70%",
    filtering: true,
    editing: true,
    inserting: true,
    sorting: true,
    paging: true,
    autoload: true,
    pageSize: 15,
    pageButtonCount: 5,
    datatype: "json",
    deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete the row?",
    controller: process_variables,
    ....................................................
```

How can I have those default size values for both js-GRID and dialog when loading it and at the same time when resizing it to autoresize both dialog and js-GRID properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by making the following change:

```
$("#DataGrid").dialog({
    minWidth: 1240,
    minHeight: 600
});
$("#DataGrid").jsGrid({
    height: "auto",
    width: "70%",
    filtering: true,
    editing: true,
    inserting: true,
    sorting: true,
    paging: true,
    autoload: true,
    pageSize: 15,
    pageButtonCount: 5,
    datatype: "json",
    deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete the row?",
    controller: process_variables,
    ....................................................
```